# Как правильно работать с DOM элементами, которые находятся в не области директивы?

Tags: angularjs, dom

Есть два div блока, они находятся на разных уровнях документа, но смещение  одного зависимо от другого. Например, при смещении первого блока, проверяем некое условие надо ли смещать второй блок, если **да** то смещаем.

Вопрос в том, как правильно организовывать такое наблюдение, написать директиву для первого блока, и там установить наблюдения за DOM элементом второго блока, **не входящим в область директивы первого блока**, или же, как то по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Решение должно исходить из дополнительных данных постановки задачи, т.е. это нужно сделать для двух дивов на странице или таких пар на странице может быть много.
Имею мнение, что лучше дивы обернуть в директивы и использовать методы для работы с событиями, они, в принципе, и предназначены для взаимодействия разных директив:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myevent');//в контроллере второй директивы

$scope.$on('myevent', function(event, args) {

});//в контроллере первой директивы
```